LyX hyperref boxes wrong placement
I started using LyX a while ago and soon I got this strange problem. The hyperref boxes doesn't cover the actual title in the table of contents.

I only used LyX's PDF properties -> Use hyperref Support menu. (I also added a border around the pages and set \geometry{textheight=245mm, textwidth=160mm, footskip=20mm}, idk if this causes this) Any idea how could I solve this?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
